# How do i fix: TypeError: unorderable types: NoneType() < float()

Tags: python-3.x, unicode, byte

i'm trying to get this code to run in Python-3.x

This is the section in which the line appears:

```
    #Here we check to make sure horizon (19) and ovveride (16) digital pins aren't on
#print("GPIO 16 (ovveride) is " + str(GPIO.input(16)))
#print("GPIO 19 (horizon) is " + str(GPIO.input(19)))
#print(GPIO.input(19))
if (GPIO.input(16) == False) and (GPIO.input(19) == False): #check to see if the passive mode switch is on
# GPIO 16 is for override and GPIO 19 is for horizon mode

#In this section we rotate as needed
    starttime = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
    if (getcurheading() > getsolarheading()) and (getsolarangle() > 2) and (getcurheading() != 999):
        while (getcurheading() > (getsolarheading() + hmargin)) and (starttime + datetime.timedelta(seconds=pan_time_limit) > datetime.datetime.utcnow()):
            if debug == True:
                print("1: Moving " + str(getcurheading()) + " to " + str(getsolarheading()))
            motor2neg()
        motors.setSpeeds(0, 0)

starttime = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
if (getcurheading() < getsolarheading()) and (getsolarangle() > 2) and (getcurheading() != 999):
    while (getcurheading() < (getsolarheading() - hmargin)) and (starttime + datetime.timedelta(seconds=pan_time_limit) > datetime.datetime.utcnow()):
        if debug == True:
            print("2: Moving " + str(getcurheading()) + " to " + str(getsolarheading()))
        motor2pos()
    motors.setSpeeds(0, 0)

starttime = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
if (getcurheading() > tomorrow_static) and (getsolarangle()<0) and (getcurheading() != 999):
    if (getcurheading() - tomorrow_static) > sleep_tolerance:
        while (getcurheading() > (tomorrow_static + hmargin)) and (starttime + datetime.timedelta(seconds=pan_time_limit) > datetime.datetime.utcnow()):
```

The error which is generated is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "solarrobot7-core.py", line 261, in <module>
    if (getcurheading() < getsolarheading()) and (getsolarangle() > 2) and (getcurheading() != 999):
TypeError: unorderable types: NoneType() < float()
```

Is this another case of Unicode strings vs. bytes?

The below is what i think is the definition of curheading.

```
#Translate the IMU from magnetic north to true north since the calcs use true north
def getcurheading():
# The escape character for # is \x23 in hex
    serialport.write(b"\x23o0 \x23f")
    headresponse = serialport.readline()
#   print(headresponse)
    words = headresponse.split(",")
    if len(words) > 2:
        try:
            curheading = (float(words[0])) + 180
            if curheading + Declination > 360: curheading = curheading - 360 + Declination
            else: curheading = curheading + Declination
        except:
            curheading = 999
#   print(curheading)
    return curheading
```

Thanks for pointing out that i didn't include the definitionj.

Comment: what is `getcurheading` ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, pvanchy!  i'll give it a try and get back to you.  As you can see i've already incorporated the "b" in     serialport.write(b"\x23o0 \x23f") because it was throwing an Unicode to bytes error.

Comment: current problem is not related to unicode issue, it's something another

Answer (score 1):

```
if (getcurheading() < getsolarheading()) and (getsolarangle() > 2) and (getcurheading() != 999):
TypeError: unorderable types: NoneType() < float()
```

This error means that your function called `getcurheading` returns `None` and the function `getsolarheading` returns `float` thats why comparison for these values is not applicable

So, I recommend you to investigate `getcurheading` function and think when it returns `None` and why. Or share this function with us

UPDATED:

As I can see from the definition of the function, you're writing to the file with a space separator, and reading with comma separator, that's why you have less than 2 items in `words` list, as a result, `curheading` variable is not defined, and a function returns `None` what is the root of your problem

if you have something like that in your file: `#o0 #f`

```
words = headresponse.split(",")
```

words will equals to `["#o0 #f']`
and you'll never inside of this loop:

```
if len(words) > 2:
```

to resolve your issue you can change this line. Replace this:

```
words = headresponse.split(",")
```

with this:

```
words = headresponse.split(" ")
```

Comment: Guess what.  Upon further inspection we found that the lines were not indented correctly.  We fixed them and everything is o.k.  We're moving on to check the next lines in this 500+ program.  Thanks for your help!